# Schema migration in django south

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I am trying to use schema migration as i have my models in which i had two models previously and i have created three more models. 
I have tried several commands like

```
python manage.py schemamigration appname --add modelname
python manage.py schemamigration appname
python manage.py schemamigration
python manage.py schemamigration appname --fake
```

but no luck

sometimes it gives me the error

```
You have not passed any of --initial, --auto, --empty, --add-model, --add-field or --add-index.
```

and sometimes this one

```
sage: manage.py schemamigration [options] 

Creates a new template schema migration for the given app

manage.py: error: ambiguous option: --add (--add-field, --add-index, --add-model?)
```

i am new to django so want some help.

Comment: If you're using a newer version of Django, south is no longer needed for schema migrations. Try using Django's baked in migration stuff. The process is to 1) make your migrations, then 2) actually apply them. The commands are: 1) python manage.py makemigrations 2) python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it

```
python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
```